# Debug.Log() is too slow to output a lot of variables quickly

Tags: c#, logging, unity-game-engine

I'm used to output variables to the console in Java, a quick and dirty way to debug and often showed me what was wrong with my code. Unfortunately using `Debug.Log` in Unity takes a lot of resources somehow. I'm currently generating a simple map in about 80ms, but since there are some problems I'd just like to output some variables, now this makes my map generate in a minute or two. Doing something like this in the update method makes Unity unresponsive and can crash without saving scene edits.

Comment: You need to show the variables and the current way you are using to output variables that makes Unity unresponsive. You can edit that into your question.

Comment: @Programmer I would love to show some code but it is irrelevant, just `Debug.Log("hello world");` 10k times each update and you see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Debug.Log()` is incredibly slow in Unity, and can really throw a wrench in performance if you're printing data at high rates (such as in a loop). A big part of the problem is all the extra processing that goes into generating those messages - aside from converting the given value to a string (which has negligible impact on performance), it also has to generate a stack trace so it can link back to the line of code where the logging occurred (see this [Unity Answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/896463/why-on-earth-debuglog-is-so-slowglitchy.html)), which is comparatively slow.

In games, it's a common practice to create an in-game debug output (think of the console in Bethesda games where you can see game events and enter developer commands). Skipping the overhead from `Debug.Log()` by writing the text you need to output into that output display saves a lot of processing power, and also lets you view debug output with less hassle on mobile devices.

The simplest solution here (short of just not logging so frequently) is to make a `Canvas` object, add a `Text` object to it for your debug output, then add a script with a few static methods to append to the `Text` content so you can reference them (and write to your display) from anywhere in your code.

Alternatively, you can write the output to a file at regular intervals if the text will be too lengthy/generated too quickly to read in real-time, then review it after the code runs.

Comment: Converting values to a string shouldn't take significant time. I'm doing this all the time outside of Unity without problems. The rest makes a lot of sense, thank you I will start making a basic and generic console that I can use in future projects too.

Comment: @Madmenyo Yeah, the string conversion likely isn't the slow part by far - it's really generating the stack trace that bogs things down. I'll make an edit to mention that. In any case, glad I could help out!