# Event listener - Random code execution order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI button and I am programatically adding a onClick listener to it. It's supposed to display a debug message first and then asynchronously start loading a scene.

For some reason it loads the scene first and then displays the message to the console.

Code below

```
void Awake()
{
    button = this.GetComponent<Button>();

    button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading level ... ");
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelName);
    });
}
```

I have went against the logic and tried logging the message after loading the scene but the result was the same.

Comment: Interestingly enough if I add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)` between the two lines it first sleeps, then logs the debug message and then begins loading the scene. I'm at my wits

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on the `Debug` line and then stepping forward to see what order it's actually happening in? It could be that `Debug` is working behind the scenes asynchronously as well.

Comment: Are you able to try `Console.WriteLine("Loading level...");` instead?

Comment: The behaviour is the same whether or not I use asynchronous loading. I do have a requirement to use the async method as I will be triggering an animation in place of the debug message.

Comment: I was simply suggesting that perhaps the `Debug` class is the issue here. If that runs asynchronously in the background in order to manage the queue of messages being managed and pushed to a console, it may affect how quickly it gets printed to console, and may cause it to be printed after your scene manager loads. I suggested trying `Console.WriteLine()` because it is a call that will block current execution until it completes, enforcing the message print happening prior to the scene loading.

Comment: I have written the previous comment before seeing yours. Anyway, Console.WriteLine does not exist in Unity's context so I'm not sure why you're suggesting it. If I try `System.Console.WriteLine()` It does not give me an error but neither does it output a message to the console.  Using breakpoints in VS2022 with Unity tools installed doesn't work for me - I will look into that

Comment: I have managed to get Visual Studio Unity tools to work. Stepping into the code line by line shows that the `Debug.Log()` line does not actually do anything until the other line gets executed and the scene is loaded.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` exists in the `System` namespace of C#, so pretty much any C# based program has access to it. If it isn't printing to the console, then the console you are seeing is one that Unity is managing.  It's most likely `Debug` having poor performance. Maybe this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939214/debug-log-is-too-slow-to-output-a-lot-of-variables-quickly

Comment: Here is another link to Unity forums: https://answers.unity.com/questions/896463/why-on-earth-debuglog-is-so-slowglitchy.html

Comment: I don't think you understand what I said. No matter how slow Debug.Log() is in Unity, if i execute that line of code and stop at the next one I should get a message show up in the console eventually. What you suggested is not the problem. If instead of logging a message to the debug console I set some random GameObject in the scene to active the behaviour is the same.

Comment: If you're stopping your program on the next line with a breakpoint and `Debug.Log` is in fact asynchronous, you won't see it print out until your program is allowed to continue execution. The debugger will have paused your application to allow you to inspect its current state. You said it prints if you run your program, which indicates that it is indeed executing the `Debug.Log` line when you execute your program. Perhaps there is more code you could show that would indicate something other than `Debug.Log` being async. Otherwise, Unity forums may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you show, logically speaking, `Debug.Log` **has to be asynchronous if it is updating the scene before printing to the console**, and therefore is probably not reliable to use without some intentional synchronization on your part.

Although the log messages themselves will show up in chronological order, they aren't necessarily being pushed to the Unity console window immediately, because the `Debug` class has to actually work across threads in order to accept log messages from anywhere.

If `Debug.Log` was a blocking call (meaning it is executed synchronously) you would see the message in the console before the next line could be executed.

Most likely what is happening in the background is this:

1. `Debug.Log` is called.
2. `Debug.Log` asynchronously adds the message to the queue and prepares to send it to console
3. When `Debug.Log` ends up `awaiting` its asynchronous piece, it yields control to the caller method (in your case, it is the lambda function you are in, and the next line is `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`)
4. The calling method then attempts to immediately execute `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` (it doesn't wait for `Debug` to finish pushing the message to the console)

If you could put some `Debug.Log` statements inside of the `LoadSceneAsync` method you would see that at the end of it all, the messages would come out in the right order, even if the scene was loaded before the first message was printed.

If you are unfamiliar with how asynchronous programming executes, I would recommend looking into some of Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

If you really wanted to see what order things are executing in, you could always create a variable that you print, instead of your message, that changes when the scene loads.

An example would be:

```
button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        AsyncOperation testVariable = null;
        Debug.Log("Loading level ... ");
        Debug.Log("testVariable is null: " + (testVariable == null));
        
        // this will be set once the SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync returns
        testVariable = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelName);
        Debug.Log("testVariable is null: " + (testVariable == null));
    });
```

This should show in the console

> Loading level...

> testVariable is null: true

> testVariable is null: false